# Play audio with MediaPlayer in single file WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, uri, wav

I'm trying to play SFX using MediaPlayer in a WPF application, but it doesn't work properly.

```cs
MediaPlayer SFX = new MediaPlayer();

SFX.Open(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/assets/audio/click.wav"));
SFX.Volume = 0.8;

SFX.Play();

SFX.MediaEnded += (o, ex) =>
{
    SFX.Close();
};
```

The 'Build Action' setting of click.wav is set to 'Resource' and the 'Copy to Output Directory' setting is set to 'Do not copy'.

(Additionally, this is the first time for the author of this post to create a WPF program using C#...)

I debugged using the code above, but I can't hear any audio.

Comment: Media player is just a wrapper around windows media player. I doubt win media player was designed to read something compiled into an exe.

Comment: Before the call to `SFX.Play()`, put in  `SFX.Position = TimeSpan.Zero`.  See if that helps.  (Might even put in a call to `SFX.Stop()` before that though it should be redundant.).  If that does not help, put in an event handler for the player's `MediaFailed` event and see if your handler gets called.

Comment: When distributing media with your application, you cannot use a media file as a project resource. In your project file, you must instead set the media type to Content and set CopyToOutputDirectory to PreserveNewest or Always.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN